# FrameTicks custom function throws "MemoryAllocationFailure"

Tags: plotting, memory, ticks

A simple function for `FrameTicks` returns memory errors when working with large powers of 10.

```
fticks = Table[{j, ScientificForm@j, {0.2, 0.}}, {j, 
     PowerRange[10.^Floor[Log10[Exp[#1]]], Exp[#2]]}] &;
LogLogPlot[10^x, {x, 9, 11}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{fticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: error message]

**SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]**

Mathematica 11.3; Ubuntu 18.04

**Edit**

If I try to print the input arguments to `FrameTick` functions using

```
fticks = Block[{}, Print["Arg 1: ", #1, "  Arg 2: " , #2]; {10^10}] &;
```

it prints out the plot range both **without** logarithms (in the Out[] cell), and **with** logarithms (in a 'Message' window that pops out).

Comment: Just to clarify: does *Mathematica* crash after evaluating this, or can you still do another evaluation afterwards?

Comment: It does not crash. I can keep working normally

Comment: What sort of `FrameTicks` are you looking to have here? Have you checked out ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` before?

Comment: In principle I want to have ticks and labels at 10^i, and small ticks at the even numbers (2,4,6,8 x10^i). For simplicity, I only posted a minimal example showing the same error.

Comment: I get the same error when I evaluate this `fticks[10^9, 10^11]`. I think the `LogLogPlot` is not germane here?

Comment: I think you're calling `PowerRange` with a very very large number?

Comment: Yes thanks. That's what I tried to say in the edit. If the input arguments are the logarithm of the PlotRange, I have to do `Exp[#1]`. But if they aren't, this leads to `Exp[10^8]`. However it is not clear whether they have the logarithm (see above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function given to FrameTicks (`FrameTicks->fticks`) is internally **evaluated twice**:

1. `fticks[10^9, 10^11]`: with the *user* plot range
2. `fticks[Log[10^9], Log[10^11]]`: with the log of the plot range

The ticks will be drawn according to the second evaluation, only if Mathematica doesn't fail during the first evaluation.

Simply tell Mathematica to avoid computations with very large numbers

```
fticks = If[Exp[#2] > (10^150), {},
...(function)... 
] &;
```

I think this is a buggy behavior, since there is apparently no reason for the first evaluation.